# Force Rails path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails, and I'm trying to create a Redmine plugin.

I want my "show" path to go to `/projects/:project_id/summary`, since the normal "show" path, `/projects/:project_id/` is already taken by the app.

I set my route to:

```
get 'projects/:project_id/summary/', to: 'summaries#show', as:  'project_summary'
```

I tested the route, and it works. However, all my attempts to write a `link_to` fail. I can only get it to link to `project/:project_id`. I don't know how to tack on the 'summary' to the path. Is there a way? I know this route is a little off the rails, and it may just not be permitted. All my other routes are Rails approved, so I'm hoping I can just bend the rules this once...

Answer (score 0):

let's say you have a project with id 8, your link_to would be:

```
@project = Project.find(8)
link_to "the project", project_summary_path(@project)
```

Also, I am assuming the model here is a `project` and not a `summary`.  If there is a summary model, you need to tell us how projects and summaries are connected in the model.  If there is a summary model that belongs_to a project, you need to adjust the routes to:

```
get 'projects/:project_id/summaries/:summary_id', to: 'summaries#show', as: 'project_summary'
```

and then your link_to would look like this:

```
@project = Project.find(8)
@summary = Summary.find(10) #assuming the id of the summary is 10
link_to "the project", project_summary_path(@project, @summary)
```

Comment: I do have a summary model that belongs_to project. 

I'm trying to do is have a list of all the projects in the database list on the left side. An init file pointing to `/summaries` which works

This is the helper code I want to point to `/projects/:project_id/summary` information to keep the project list on the left side.

`def render_project_hierarchy(projects)

    render_project_nested_lists(projects) do |project|

      link_to_project(project, {}, action: "show", id: @project_id , :class => "#{project.css_classes} #{User.current.member_of?(project) ? 'my-project' : nil}")`

Comment: Post another question and I'm happy to answer it, but I believe my post answers your initial question.  Please mark as correct if that is true.

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine as is. One caveat with routes, if you want this path to be used instead of the default rails, simply list it first in the routes file:

```
get 'projects/:project_id/summary/', to: 'summaries#show', as:  'project_summary'
resources :projects
resources :summaries
```

If you run `rake routes`, the output of this looks like:

```
project_summary GET    /projects/:project_id/summary(.:format) summaries#show
          projects GET    /projects(.:format)                     projects#index
                   POST   /projects(.:format)                     projects#create
       new_project GET    /projects/new(.:format)                 projects#new
      edit_project GET    /projects/:id/edit(.:format)            projects#edit
           project GET    /projects/:id(.:format)                 projects#show
```

If you visit /projects/1 or /projects/1/summary, you should see the same view.

The link_to is simply the alias you gave it:

```
<%= link_to 'show', project_summary_path(@project_instance_id) %>
```

Whereas, the default Rails link_to (in this example) would be:

```
<%= link_to 'show', project_path(@project_instance_id) %>
```